# Ignite Vs KDb - Which is better?

Tags: ignite, kdb, in-memory, bigdata

Which is a better in-memory technology for fast computations on big data - Kdb or Ignite? Ignite provides caching to store huge amount of data and we can perform SQL operations on it. Kdb is also an in-memory database which provides very fast computation on time-series data. In my use case, I don't need to update data. I just need to use the historical data on-the-fly for some computations. I tried out myself and Kdb gave much better performance numbers as compared to Ignite. I am new to Ignite though, so I might be missing something here. So, just wanted to confirm which technology is better in the use case mentioned. There has been no direct comparison provided anywhere on internet.

Can somebody please through some light on this?

Comment: I think couple of things need to be considered in that comparison. First, currently how you store your hdb data? Is it using KDB or some other technology?

Comment: Yes, in my use case Ignite cache is supposed to load data from kdb services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDB is a column-store database. Ignite is row-store.
So the performance depends on your data layout and the kind of computations that you run.

If you provide the code, Ignite community may help with performance advice.

Comment: Consider median calculation as an example on a particular column based on some filters.

Comment: @PoojaMazumdar well, obviously, column-based DB will have a huge advantage for a single-column computations. So KDB may be a better choice for you.

Comment: Hi Pavel, yeah it seems to be a better option. But KDb is really bad at handling multiple queries at a time. This is the main reason why I am exploring Ignite.

Comment: Kdb has multithreaded and distributed architecture options - there are no concerns with handling simultaneous requests on well-designed systems

Comment: Hi, could you please share some links which I can refer for multithreaded architecture?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using KDB for your data as you mentioned then adding Ignite layer on top of it would not be a good idea. KDB itself is in-memory database and highly optimized for that. It outperforms many other in-memory database systems by a good margin.

You need to consider your operations behavior on data. If they are mostly column oriented then no doubt KDB would be a better choice.

Ignite core idea is distributed in-memory database which is again KDB also good at. And KDB is more simple to scale and maintain.

Only if you have other database for ex. Hadoop then adding Ignite layer on top of it might give better performance but again that need to be tested.

To see KDB comparisons to other systems, check these links:

http://kparc.com/q4/readme.txt

http://kparc.com/q4/q4.txt

Comment: Yes KDb seems to be a better option performance wise but the only caveat here is multiple queries can't be fired on kdb service at a time as far as I know. So, if one query is already fired on the kdb service and another request comes in, the service becomes unavailable for the second query. And the service is expected to have huge number of requests in my use-case.

Comment: You can look into KDB  multi process feature or gateway architecture for load balanced system. They are simple to implement ad scale. Check this example implementation from Kevin:
 http://kxcommunity.com/demo-of-query-routing-in-kx-for-scalable-load-balanced-system.php

Comment: We expect hundreds of requests per second. So creating gateway doesn't appear to be feasible in this case. I'll look into multi process feature. thanks for the information.